# Find the generic type passed into a function

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have created a generic function that passes in, one specific type and another 'generic' type.

```
func initializeCategory<T: UIView> (category: Category, type: T) {

//Find which type 'type' is

//If type is of type, 'UIView' -> do something
//else if type is of type, 'Category' or another type -> Do something else

}
```

What I'm trying to do is find what type is passed in as a generic type in my function?

Is there a better way to create a generic function that can query the different types passed into it?

Or should I set it like this `<T: Any>`??

P.S Category is a subclass of UIView

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is a generic constraint function.

Here is the constraints:

```
        view.addSubview(categoryOne)
        categoryOne.delegate = self
        categoryOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        categoryOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        categoryOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

        categoryOne.heightConstraint = categoryOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        categoryOne.heightConstraint?.isActive = true
```

What I need is the ability to change the 'top Anchor' constraint. So if I pass in the type of UIView, it would be set as `is = constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor` etc

However if I pass in type of Category (which subclasses UIView), then I need to change the constraint(equalTo: category.bottomAnchor etc

--  I thought if have a generic function they querying which type is passed in, I could get a result.

Comment: Is type(of : type) working?

Comment: Cannot call value of non-function type 'T'

Comment: If Category is subclass of UIView, you don't need to change `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor` in function. You can pass Category directly as `view`.

Comment: I solved it. By removing get the whole generics, and just placing the second parameter of type: UIView, then checking which type is what. Would you recommend a more efficient way?

Comment: great to heat that. I have no at this point

Comment: Ok thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `type` as an argument as it is a keyword. The following code works.

```
func initializeCategory<T: UIView> (category: Category, type1: T) {


 let a =   type(of :type1)
    print(a)

 }

    or 


   switch  type1 {
    case  is SKView:
            print(1)
    default:
        print(2)
    }
```

Comment: I need to check if type, is of type UIView or Category, or other types

Comment: if let a = type(of: type1) {
            //Do something
        } else {
            //Do something else
        }

Comment: I get an error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'T.Type'

Comment: override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view);
          initializeCategory(type1: view )
    }

Comment: I used it in above function and the a is SKView which is one subclass ofUIView. Don't use `if let a =` , just use a. You may consider use `switch type1{ case is SKView: print(1)  ;  default: break; }`

Answer (score 0):

***SOLVED***

```
func initializeCategory (category: Category, type: UIView) {
        view.addSubview(category)
        category.delegate = self

    if type == view {
        category.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: type.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    } else {
        category.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: type.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).isActive  = true
    }

    category.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    category.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

    category.heightConstraint = category.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    category.heightConstraint?.isActive = true
}
```